# black screen on booting into Ubuntoon Windows 7 PC - Nvidia card

Tags: nvidia, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 desktop AMD 64 on a PC running Windows 7 and the dual booting worked just fine, but "something" happened.  Now, When choosing Ubuntu at start-up, only a blank screen appears.  Since the graphics card is Nvidia  (GPU processor: GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 Driver version: 186.55), I hoped the following steps from another post would help:

*If your graphics card is Nvidia, follow these steps:
    In the GRUB menu at startup, press "e"; then
    Use the arrow keys to replace quiet splash with no splash or nomodeset.
    Then press the CTRL+X key combination to boot.*

There is no "quiet splash" text to edit.  I tried adding "no splash" as the final line, but upon "CTRL-X", the system booted into Windows, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

"Nomodeset" is the one I've had most luck with.

Try again with "nomodeset" and not "no splash". And don't replace anything, just type it in at the end of the row.